# Why does wordpress add_action() function requires a $accepted_args param?

Tags: php, wordpress

In my search of creating a hook system i found wordpress to be a very good example and i am trying to mimic it's `add_action()` and `do_action()` function calls.
However, in wordpress, the function signature is:

```
add_action( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
```

and it requires the `$accepted_args` params to be passed (defaults to 1) in order to raise `do_action()` properly.

In my class methods, i don't see the need why a param for `$accepted_args` should be passed:

```
public function addAction($tag, $callback, $priority = 10)
{
    if (empty($tag) || !is_callable($callback)) {
        return $this;
    }

    if (!$this->getActionsMap()->contains($tag)) {
        $this->getActionsMap()->add($tag, new CList());
    }

    $this->getActionsMap()->itemAt($tag)->add(array(
        'callback'  => $callback,
        'priority'  => (int)$priority,
    ));

    return $this;
}

public function doAction($tag, $arg = null)
{
    if (!$this->getActionsMap()->contains($tag)) {
        return $this;
    }

    $actions = $this->getActionsMap()->itemAt($tag)->toArray();
    $sort = array();
    foreach ($actions as $action) {
        $sort[] = (int)$action['priority'];
    }
    array_multisort($sort, $actions);

    $args = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);
    array_unshift($args, $arg);

    foreach ($actions as $action) {
        call_user_func_array($action['callback'], $args);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

So i am wondering, is there a real reason why that param is needed, something obvious that i am missing? Or it's just because of the legacy code in wordpress?

Comment: I'm missing something in your question.  Why do you say it's required if it defaults to 1?  Doesn't that mean you can call `add_action` without supplying it?

Comment: i mean it is required in case your action expects more than one param, in that case you need to supply the number of params, otherwise will throw an error i think.

Comment: Only the WordPress devs can tell you why they *chose* this approach, the best SO can offer is speculation based on best practices. Your approach is "Better too many arguments than too few", WordPress apparently thinks "Better too few arguments than too many". With their way, you can register the same handler with multiple different numbers of arguments, if you can think of a use for it.

Comment: @DCoder `With their way, you can register the same handler with multiple different numbers of arguments` -- i guess that's the only reason, but for now i can't think why i would register same handler with different declarations, this just makes things confusing in my opinion. Thanks for the insights.